# Tweaked formating of date with days of week, and mounts

Tags: android, design-patterns, datetime, date, formatting

Well instead of 2011.10.19 10:30 I want to have something like 10:30, Wednesday or instead of 2011.09.19 10:30 I want to have something like 10:30, September. I know that I can code this somehow but I want clean and not greedy solution. The code will run on android devices so I need something that acts gracefully with resources and something that is well written. PreatyTime doesn't helps me cause it calculates distance from this moment , and there is no formatting like 12:00, Monday.
Does someone know some good pattern that I can follow when writing this kind of things ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

It will give you any format you want,by just passing a Calendar object.

For example:

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
String myFormat=String.format("%1$tH:%1$tM %1$tB",cal);
```

would give you format like "10:30 September".